# Info on STA509A MOSFET Array

Tags: mosfet, datasheet

I am trying to find information about the different variants of the STA509A MOSFET Array. The only datasheet I can find is a one-pager that doesn't have any details about the different variants. As you can see from the photo below, I have a 3618, which works in my project, and a 1608, which doesn't. The 1608 just overheats and behaves erratically when I apply power to one of the gate pins. Unfortunately after getting my project working with the 3618 I ordered a batch of them and received 1608s. I wasn't aware of the difference when I ordered.

I know it's a long shot, but I was hoping there might be someone here who has knowledge of these things or might have a more complete datasheet. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: According to the datasheet, the 1608 or 3618 is a lot number, not a different device.

Comment: @PeterBennett you are right. I was looking for more, but I see that in the image on the datasheet now. Apparently I got a batch of bad parts.  If you want to answer the question, I would be happy to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the datasheet, the 1608 or 3618 is a lot number, not a different device.